# Connect to MongoDB failed when using .NET Core running on Linux

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm building a website using ASP.NET Core 2.0 (just upgraded from 1.1 one month ago). MongoDB is hosted by Mongo Atlas on AWS as well.This MongoDB instance has 3 replica set, require SSL to connect and already set can be access from any IP.

It runs quite ok on my machine (Windows 10 x64) and AWS (Windows Server 2016).

I try to deploy it on Linux machines, I use apt to install `dotnet-runtime-2.0.0` on Ubuntu Server 16.04, then I try to run my site , and got the following error (for security reason I hide the exact server domain name)

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-00-*****.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-00-*****.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command isMaster failed: no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell..
```

and two same error for the rest of replica set.

But I can successfully connect to MongoDB server by MongoDB shell use the same machine.

Am I missing some dependencies on Ubuntu or there's a bug in MongoDB .NET SDK?

Full stacktrace:

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-00-*****.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-00-*****.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command isMaster failed: no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell..
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-01-*****.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-01-*****.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command isMaster failed: no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell..
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-02-*****.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/*****-shard-00-02-*****.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command isMaster failed: no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell..
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()" }] }.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CreateIndexesOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.MongoIndexManager.CreateMany(IEnumerable`1 models, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoIndexManagerBase`1.CreateOne(IndexKeysDefinition`1 keys, CreateIndexOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: This part `Command isMaster failed: no SNI name sent,` tells us there is something wrong with either the connection string you are sending or the replica set configuration. If it's Altas hosted and you used the website tools to deploy the replica set rather than doing it yourself then it's likely the connection string. If you "did" do your own replica set configuration, and added the members and config manually instead, then that could also be a potential problem. You should be using the "public" IP addresses or to be more specific the assigned names in DNS for those hosts.

Comment: At any rate, you need to look at which one of those applies ( or both ) and actually supply as much as you can representing the connection string in use for your code and/or the replica set configuration. Latter is obtainable from `rs.config()` using a mongo shell connected to any member instance.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for reply. Something I need to explain is that Mongo Atlas is an official managed MongoDB service, I don't have privilege to execute "rc.config()" command. And the most wired part is this project run perfectly in Windows and Windows Server, but goes wrong on Linux. But I can connect and execute commands by MongoDB commandline tools in Linux using the same MongoDB connection string in my project.

Comment: We know what Atlas is. If you don't have the privilege then that is simply because the account you are using lacks the privilege. MongoDB does not "lock out" access to this, so it's up to you to arrange a privileged account. I am also telling you that there are several "possible reasons". Therefore if there is no problem with the configuration, the problem is with your connection. At either rate you were asked to ["add detail to your question"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47259697/edit), which you have not yet done. So you're looking in the wrong place. Not Windows vs Linux, but "config"

Comment: @YankeeYu I'm getting the same error. Works all fine from my windows development machine but throws the same error on linux. Tried different options with the connection string but no luck. Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.NET Core library does not support the SNI TLS extension on Linux and OSX.

Hence you will not be able to connect to a FREE Tier MongoDB Atlas.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#c-net-driver-example

> IMPORTANT The .NET Core library does not support the SNI TLS extension
>   on Linux and OSX. Applications using .NET Core on these operating
>   systems cannot connect to a Atlas Free Tier cluster.
>
> The issue is tracked on the [dotnet/corefx github page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9608).

Comment: SNI support is already implemented in .NET Core 2.1 preview: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17427 and with this patch MongoDb Driver works fine.