# dotnet core lambda endpoint that calls mongoDb with outbound connection returns timeout error after thirty seconds

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have a dotnet application which I'm trying to deploy to aws lambda. However it can't connect to the external database (hosted on Atlas).

Atlas is white listed for all incoming IP addresses and I can connect from my dev machine using the connection string.

When pushed to the staging environment it seems to be struggling with getting an outbound http connection.

I've set the mongoClient timeout to 15 secs hoping to get some further information about why it won't connect but the timeout continues to be 30 seconds.

The code works locally so I'm guessing its something to do with the cloudformation template not allowing outbound connections?

Many Thanks

**I think this is looking like the issue...will update once tried fix**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47672070/4996549

**Reference to similar issue**
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/247

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description" : "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",

  "Parameters" : {
  },

  "Conditions" : {
  },

  "Resources" : {

    "ProxyFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "arcane.ultimatechyoa.api::arcane.ultimatechyoa.api.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.0",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 512,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
          }
        },
        "Events": {
          "PutResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "RootPathFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "arcane.ultimatechyoa.api::arcane.ultimatechyoa.api.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.0",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 512,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
          }
        },
        "Events": {
          "PutResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs" : {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation template doesn't have any role in this. Check if Database is publicly accessible. If it is accessible only through private network, you will have to create a VPC in AWS and configure it in lambda function.

Lambda can run for maximum 300 seconds. 30 second is the default timeout for lambda.

Comment: It is publicly available and I can get access to it from my local machine.